# Selenium - how to make driver wait till DOM element is finished refreshing

Tags: java, selenium, automation, wait

I have a  element in DOM of a page i'm trying to automate. This table has a list of items(shopping cart, 1 `<li>` - 1 row). I am removing items by clicking on a button and i want to wait until the table is finished refreshing.

I don't want to use `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stanelessOf()` because i want this script to be adjustable and not focus on a specific number of an element in the list. Neither i want to use `Thread.sleep` because it doesn't look elegant.
I'm doing it in studying purposes, otherwise i would probably find a simpler way to do this, but not it wouldn't be so "elegant" and i wouldn't learn anything new.

Comment: wait for <table> element to refresh. sorry. i don't know how to edit my post.

Comment: click on the `edit` link below that `java` `selenium` `...` tags

Comment: @VladKorol, does it show any loader while refreshing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Only children of <table> element change, the web-page is not refreshing.

Comment: e.g - i have 3 lines with some record. I remove an item from a cart and only 2 items stay. web-page doesn't refresh, but table is refreshing

Comment: Because you have a dynamic table that doesn't need to refresh the page, also selenium elements change instantly when the DOM changes even when you don't refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:
This code waits for the visibility of the element using "ExpectedConditions"

```
String xPathSplit = <xpath>
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPathSplit)));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also `visibilityOfElementLocated` can be replaced with `elementToBeClickable`

Answer (score 0):

The following code checks the document status itself using the Javascript Executor:

```
public void waitForPageToLoad() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        public Boolean apply(WebDriver wdriver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    });
}
```